# Convert Dictionary to String

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have

```
  dic = {'value': '123','sort': 'desc','type': 'float'}
```

I want it become string like:

```
 str = 'value=123&sort=desc&type=float'
```

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Is this for use in a HTTP request? If so, have a look at `urllib.urlencode`.

Comment: i don't think that's very difficult when you can simply implode the array.

Comment: This wont work with dictionaries since items are not stored in a specific order. Use OrderedDict instead.

Comment: @EisaAdil if it is for a url, then you need to worry about escaping

Comment: @EisaAdil: what's an "array"? What's "imploding"? Are you sure you're talking about Python?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know Python. I come from PHP. 

It looked like an assoc array to me. So the first thing that came to mind in implode.

Comment: Does the order of the items matter? The contents of a dictionary are not ordered, so the (key, value) pairs in one will occur in a seemingly random order when the they're iterated.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
dic={'value':'123','sort':'desc','type':'float'}     
str=''
for i in dic:
    str = str + i + '=' + dic[i] + '&'
str[:-1]
```

Or with list comprehension and reduce:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [i+'='+dic[i]+'&' for i in dic])[:-1]
```

Comment: Down-voting because both are very inefficient and generally "unPythonic".

Comment: reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [i+'='+dic[i]+'&' for i in dic])[:-1] working with me . i am using it. Not bug.

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
>>> d = {'value':'123','sort':'desc','type':'float'}
>>> "&".join(["{}={}".format(k, v) for k, v in d.items()])
'sort=desc&type=float&value=123'
>>>
```

As pointed out in many of the comments; if this is for a HTTP Request, use the `urllib.urlencode` function.

```
>>> from urllib import urlencode
>>> urlencode(d)
'sort=desc&type=float&value=123'
>>>
```

Comment: I remember your [generate password](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578468-password-generator-mkpasswd/) code @active-state.

Comment: I do like list comprehension :)

Answer (score 6):

Can also be done with urllib

```
import urllib
d = {'value':'123','sort':'desc','type':'float'}
urllib.urlencode(d)
'sort=desc&type=float&value=123'
```

Answer (score 1):

This wont work with dictionaries if you care about the order of the string elements since the items are not stored in a specific order. Use OrderedDict instead.

Unless the resulting string has always the same format so you could use the format notation

```
>>> dic={'value':'123','sort':'desc','type':'float'} 
>>> str='value={value}&sort={sort}&type={type}'.format(**dic)
```

Comment: Query String parameter order do not matter.

Comment: While this works around (a possible) ordering issue, it's very not generic in the sense that it requires the key values to be hardcoded into the format string.